# Isometries of Compact Semisimple Lie Groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, isometries

In [this delightful question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75742/isometry-group-of-a-homogeneous-space), the poster mentioned that the isometry group of a compact Lie group $G$, equipped with the metric from the Killing form, is $G\times G/Z(G)$, where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$. I'm specifically interested in the Riemannian case, so I will add the extra condition that $G$ be semisimple.

> Is there a concise way to show that $G\times G/Z(G)$ is the isometry group, other than using the algorithm from the answer?

I can clearly see that it is a subgroup, since the metric coming from the Killing form is bi-invariant, and that quotienting out the center from one of the two copies of $G$ is necessary, because otherwise the action wouldn't be faithful. However, I cannot see how all isometries are of that form. In fact, I'm almost positive that this would exclude something of finite order, like $g\mapsto g^{-1}$.

Comment: Note that @RobertBryant's answer gives the Lie algebra of the isometry group, rather than the full isometry group, and as such shows only that the group that you have described is the *identity component* of the isometry group.  It is not surprising that finite-order isometries live in different components!

Comment: Googling "isometry group of a Lie group" turned up the paper Ochiai and Takahashi - "The group of isometries of a left-invariant Riemannian metric on a Lie group" (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01360280), which confirms that it is indeed the identity component which is being identified here.  (In turn that article attributes it to p. 207 of Helgason, "Differential geometry and symmetric spaces", I think Theorem 4.1 (https://books.google.com/books?id=xf_YVHF51MwC&pg=PA207).)

Comment: @LSpice -- I see. I guess my confusion in that respect stems from no assumptions of connectedness being stated, so I just assumed that it meant the whole group. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the first sentence of @RobertBryant's answer is "Here is an algorithm to compute *the Lie algebra* of the group of isometries of a homogeneous space $G/H$ endowed with a $G$-invariant (pseudo-)Riemannian metric $g$" (emphasis mine).  That is, he does explicitly mention (though I missed it at first!) that he is only identifying the Lie algebra; and the Lie algebra of a Lie group, which explicitly 'zooms in' near the identity, only ever has a chance of identifying the identity component.

Comment: @LSpice -- Yes, I saw this. My question regards the question's post, not the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to fuss, and I'll let it go after this, but note that, despite the post's *title*, the actual text following the text '**Question**' is "Is there a way to determine the isometry *Lie algebra* of a homogeneous pseudoriemannian manifold $G/H$, preferably by algebraic means from the data $(\mathfrak g,\mathfrak h)$ and the $\mathfrak h$-invariant inner product on $\mathfrak m$?" (again, emphasis mine).

Comment: @LSpice -- "The **group** G is a subgroup of the **isometry group** of M, but it need not be the full isometry group. For example, we could have M be a **compact Lie group** G with the natural bi-invariant metric coming from (minus) the Killing form on the Lie algebra. Clearly G acts transitively on G via left multiplication, but the **full isometry group** is G×G (modulo the centre, if we insist that the isometry group acts effectively)." Emphasis mine.